# Every group of prime order is cyclic Then, Is prime order subgroup of a non-cyclic group whose order is not prime also cyclic?

Tags: group-theory

I tried the dihedral group $D_3$ of order $6$ which is not cyclic. I take the subgroup containing the three rotations ($R_0$, $R_{120}$, $R_{240}$) it is cyclic. Does it work for all groups?

Comment: Yes, **any** group of order $p$ is cyclic, in particular such subgroups. For dihedral groups $D_n$, the subgroup of rotations $C_n$ is always cyclic, not only for $n=3$.

Comment: Every group of prime order is cyclic. A subgroup of prime order is a group. Hence it is cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subgroup is itself **a group**. The "sub-" prefix is just there to indicate that the underlying set is a subset of a larger set.

Since the theorem works for any group and a subgroup is again a **group**, the subgroup has to behave according to the theorem regardless of the larger group that the subgroup is contained.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a group $G$ of order $n$, where $n$ is not prime and $G$ is non-cyclic. Let $N$ be any subgroup of $G$ of prime order $p$. By Lagrange's Theorem, there can only be two subgroups of $N$, $N$ itself and $\{e\}$. It thus follows that there exists an element $x \in N$ which generates $N$. Thus $N$ is a cyclic group of prime order, i.e. $N \simeq C_p$.